# calling jQuery function under componentDidMount() prevents onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm applying some theme stuffs on **React Component** for that I'm importing third party jQuery `min.js` file and calling a method inside that file in `componentDidMount()` method. It works fine as predicted but it's preventing `onChange()` method of `<select>`. I don't know what is happening after execution of those jQuery statements.
Here is my component **SingleSelect.js**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'

import map                  from "lodash/map"
import $                    from 'jquery';

import "../../app/assets/vendors/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"
class SingleSelect extends React.Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    $(this.refs.singleselect).select2({
        placeholder: this.props.placeholder
    });
  }

  changed(){console.log("Changed")}

  render () {
    const taged_options = map(this.props.options, (val, key) =>
                <option key={ key } value={val}>{val} </option>
    )

    return (
      <div className="form-group">
        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          {this.props.label}
        </label>
        <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <select
            onChange={this.changed}
            ref="singleselect"
            className="form-control"
            value="Wholesaler"
            name={this.props.name}
          >
            {taged_options}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

SingleSelect.propTypes = {
  label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  required: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  options: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

SingleSelect.defaultProps = {
  placeholder: "Select a value from list"
};

export default SingleSelect
```

Comment: I want to bind it with its parent's onChange().

Comment: Can you provide fiddle or jsbin?

Comment: I don't know how to make this work on jsfiddle. Because to encounter this error it's required to import select2.full.min.js and jQuery also. I tried but failed. I just got the solution. But still I want to know why is this happening and what's wrong with my code? @Jyothi Babu Araja

Comment: I think `select2` is preventing the `event` on `select` element. We can hack that if you can reproduce that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I faced a similar issue when using select2. I would suggest you to use react-select2-wrapper library. It gives onClick event separately. Also you can run your JQuery code parallely in components. This is one hack by which I bypassed this problem when using select2

Comment: So doesn't this react-select2-wrapper wrap css stuffs other than just jQuery?

Comment: Hey it's throwing this error now, after I bound its onChange like
onChange={this.props.onChange}
Error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: So you might be doing something which makes it to repeat on change. Either a props change or state change of that component. Can you provide the fiddle ?

Comment: Alright, it was my typo. Solved. But here is my other question... Doesn't this 'react-select2-wrapper' wrap css stuffs inside?

Comment: You can manually serve the select2.css file to make it work. In the guides section of github page you can see the last line how to do it. But I never tried using inline styles or passing it.